Is the product integral positive?
Let $f$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{S}^1$ with $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$. Can the integral
$$\int_{0}^r\iint_{|x-y|<t}f(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}t$$
be nonnegative for all $r>0$? Here $x,y\in\mathbb{S}^1$ and $t\in [0,r]$. By $|x-y|$ I mean the distance of $x$ and $y$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$.
Since the integral is nonnegative for small $r$ and remains constant when $r>\pi$, it seems possibly the conclusion holds. But I can't prove it. On the other hand I didn't find any counterexample. Many thanks in advance for any helpful thoughts!

Is this a triple integral? Or a double integral and a function of t ?

@Sam It's a double integral and a function of t.  Updated.
